# Drag audio files out of a media player

Tags: windows, media-player

I recall a feature in an older Amarok version (Linux), where you could select tracks in your music library and drag them out of the player, directly to a folder on your harddrive. Does anyone know of a media player on Windows that supports this?

This is very useful when you keep one "core-library" of your music on your computer, and keep all your ratings there. You can then simply connect any other device, and drag/drop all the tracks with a rating higher than X, or with a play-count lower/higher than Y...

Or am i missing another useful way of doing this?

Comment: Foobar can do this

Comment: I have Foobar v1.3.1 installed, and it doesn't work for me. It shows the copy-icon when i drag to a folder, but the file doesn't copy when i let go. Also, Foobar lacks too many features out of the box to be useful for me, and the support and community seems to be in decline over the last years. Still, if it could do this it would be useful for one-off shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Mp3tag seems to be able to do this.
It's not a media-player, but it does allow applying filters on all tags, including rating and genre. As a result, i can use this to easily export subsets of my music library to other platforms and devices.